# EntityFramework ComplexType referencing EntityType

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am rather new to EntityFramework's Code First approach and I'm getting the following error when I try to to create a reusable complex type that references an entity type.

Models:

```
 class Bank
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
 class BankAccount
{
    public Bank Bank { get; set; }
    public int BankId { get; set; }
    public int Agency { get; set; }
    public int Account { get; set; }

}
 class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public BankAccount BankAccount { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
class DemoContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Bank> Banks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Bank>().HasKey(b => b.Code);
        modelBuilder.ComplexType<BankAccount>();

    }

}
```

When I try to add a Migration I get the following error:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

ComplexTypeProblem.EF.Bank: Name: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'Bank' is already defined.
ComplexTypeProblem.EF.Bank: : EntityType 'Bank' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Banks: EntityType: EntitySet 'Banks' is based on type 'Bank' that has no keys defined.
```

Is there any caveat to implement this kind of relationship where a ComplexType has a navigation property to an EntityType?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a **ComplexType** containing an **EntityType**. Only the other way around.

**ComplexTypes** are simply properties for an entity, and they should work on your code just like normal fields.

Comment: I've done that by adding this line to the OnModelCreating callback: modelBuilder.Entity<Bank>().HasKey(b => b.Code);

Comment: My bad. I edited my answer with updated information.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to set up a 1 -> many mapping for the Bank / BankAccounts?  If so, I would recommend the following:

```
public partial class Bank
{
  public Bank()
  {
    BankAccounts = new List<BankAccount>();
  }

  public int Code { get; set;}
  public string Name { get; set;}

  public virtual ICollection<BankAccount> BankAccounts { get; set;}
}
public partial class BankAccount
{
  public int BankId { get; set;}
  public int Agency { get; set;}
  public int Account { get; set;}

  public virtual Bank Bank { get; set;}
}
```

And change the OnModelCreating method as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Bank>().HasKey(b => b.Code);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Bank>().HasMany(m => m.BankAccounts).WithRequired(r => r.Bank).HasForeignKey(f => f.BankId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. But what I really want is ask for a solution that conceptually matches the scenario I described. In my "real world" application I have a list of counties the user can choose from and an Address complex type that I would like to reuse every time.

I've searched Google a lot for this kind of answer but couldn't find an answer for this kind of problem specifically.